# syntax error, unexpected 'Â Â Â Â ' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

Why does my PHP mailing code always give:

> syntax error, unexpected 'Â Â Â Â ' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\GSP\members.php on line 4

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {
     
    $email_to = 'kennydharmawan@gmail.com'; //this is line 4
    $email_subject = "GSP Rent Order";
     
     
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
     
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['unit']) ||
        !isset($_POST['startdate']) ||
        !isset($_POST['enddate']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['rname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['city']) ||
        !isset($_POST['adress'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
     
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $rname = $_POST['rname'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress'];
     
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    $phone_exp = "/^[1-9][0-9]{0,15}$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$rname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Recipient Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$city)) {
    $error_message .= 'The City you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($phone_exp,$telephone)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($adress) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Adress you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  list($dd,$mm,$yyyy) = explode('/',$startdate);
  if (!checkdate($mm,$dd,$yyyy)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Start Date you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  list($dd,$mm,$yyyy) = explode('/',$enddate);
  if (!checkdate($mm,$dd,$yyyy)) {
        $error_message .= 'The End Date you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
     
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Unit: ".clean_string($unit)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Start Date: ".clean_string($startdate)."\n";
    $email_message .= "End Date: ".clean_string($enddate)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone Number: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Recipient Name: ".clean_string($rname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Recipient City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Recipient Adress: ".clean_string($adress)."\n";
     
     
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon."
}
?>
```

Why does it always keep saying this error?

Comment: What encoding did you save your document in?

Comment: It sometimes happens that you accidentially save some exotic unpritable character without noticing it. Try really deleting that line and rewriting it.

Comment: Weird. Your code gives me a syntax error on the last `echo`.

Comment: You are sure that is the right script you posted? The error is said to be in file 'members.php', but this script hendles a form submitssion...

Comment: im using dreamweaver btw, and i use this code as an action for my form action page

Comment: which unicode normalization form that should i use in saving the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the PHP file has been saved with exotic white space characters -- ie not standard spaces, but some other characters that are rendered as spaces (or even not shown at all), but are unparseable by PHP.

Delete all the white space characters on lines 3 and 4, re-type them, and save the file. (that's *all* white space, including line feeds and spaces between words)

This should solve the problem.

If after doing this, you still get the error, but on a different line, then you will need to repeat the process for that line too.

Comment: This solves my issue too, just to mention that I got this problem while copy-pasting some code from internet, from SyntaxHighlighter to Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your code:

Try replacing:

```
$email_to = 'kennydharmawan@gmail.com';
```

With:

```
$email_to = "kennydharmawan@gmail.com";
```

And in this line:

```
echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon."
```

Your are missing an ";", so fixed it:

```
echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.";
```

PS: Try replacing all your single quotes with double quotes( '' with "") i all your strings vars ;)

Saludos.

Comment: Why should double-quotes be better than single-quotes?

Comment: It's better because in this way your code is more readable, and in this way you don't have a mix of things.....i allways use one way, or another, but never a mix of things.....for me those mixes = hard to find bugs in the future ;)

Comment: @RobertRozas - mixed quote styles is perfectly legitimate, and perfectly readable. And it has nothing whatever to do with the answer to this question.

Comment: If it's so easy and readable, then, where is the error??....al already say that i found an error and he miss and ; in the "Trank you" echo....the other stuff it's an advice-tip ;) ....sorry anyway