# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Â Â Â ' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Â Â Â ' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\Banking\Banking.php on line 5

```
interface Execution
{
 public function execute();
}
```

Line 5 is referring to `public function execute();`

What is wrong with the interface?

I checked the other problems with the same error but cant find one that is related to this.

Comment: i didn't get any error:-https://eval.in/655125     please provide some more detail and code too

Comment: Maybe you have some wonky hidden character in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067407/why-does-my-website-always-runs-syntax-error-unexpected-%C3%82-%C3%82-%C3%82-%C3%82-t-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with encoding.

Please convert your file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM

[HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Comment: Doubt it.  &nbsp; won't be valid in PHP either.

Comment: i deleted the interface and typed it over and now it is not bringing up the error any more but it finds problem with the lines after that...sjoe...yor!!!